# Converting human readable date and time into Unix time float

Tags: python, unix, time

I have to convert date and time returned by ls of rsync into Unix epoch time float as returned by time.time().

For me here at this moment it looks like:
2017/05/24 hh:mm:ss.
But as far as I know it can vary from machine to machine as rsync uses ssh and native ls, I expect through it.

Is there any easy way to universally convert most common human readable date and time back to the Unix time float?
To be clear. I want to be able to convert any textual representation of D and T into the float.

If datetime can do this I cannot find how at the moment.

Comment: For `ls`, you can use `ls -l '--time-style=+%s'` to specify how the time should be formatted. It actually does *not* depend on the distro, but more on the `locale`: the cultural settings on how to denote time/date. I think it is for instance possible that a machine configured in Israel, will use the Jewish year.

Comment: Well, yes, I am certain that ls respects local settings, which doesn't help me at all. Especially as I am using rsync to get to the ls. I'll see whether I can influence the time output format from there, but I doubt it. I'll probably end up using ssh directly to get to stats of files, but it would be nice to know if Python can do the conversion. It would simplify some stuff a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html#time.strftime) first and then [calendar.timegm](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/calendar.html?highlight=calendar.timegm#calendar.timegm)
there are different options depending if you want to convert to local time or UTC time. Have a look to the documentation for that.
To get the float part, you need to input hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. In your example, you give only the year, month and day, so the rest is supposed to be zero i.e. no milliseconds thus no float part.

Here a minimal example:

```
import calendar, time

t = time.strptime('2017/05/24', '%Y/%m/%d')
epoch = calendar.timegm(time.struct_time(t))
print(epoch)

1495584000
```

Comment: Excellent! time.ctime(epoch) gives 'WedMay  24 00:00:00 2017'  I knew it was something like that! This doesn't automate format recognition though. It would be splendid if it is implemented too. Perhaps something can be done with regex.

Comment: You just need to decide the format it can work with any format, for example time.strptime('2017/05/24 23:45:04', "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") check this table https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: If you have non-uniform formats then you have to make specific cases for each of them.